# How to set the default theme from colors spinner in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner, android-theme

I make a spinner to select theme color and it work and set the activity theme
but when close the application and open it again the default theme is appear not the last choose and this my codes can anyone tell me what can i change

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{

            add(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.redPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.pinkPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.greenPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.tealPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.purplePrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.lightBluePrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.yellowPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.orangePrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.brownPrimaryDark);
            add(R.color.greyPrimaryDark);
}};

private Spinner Colors_Spinner;
private int Colors_currentSelectedItemPosition = 0;


final Integer colors2[] = {
        R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
        R.color.redPrimaryDark,
        R.color.pinkPrimaryDark,
        R.color.greenPrimaryDark,
        R.color.tealPrimaryDark,
        R.color.purplePrimaryDark,
        R.color.lightBluePrimaryDark,
        R.color.yellowPrimaryDark,
        R.color.orangePrimaryDark,
        R.color.brownPrimaryDark,
        R.color.greyPrimaryDark};

CustomSpinnerAdapter customSpinnerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    // MUST BE SET BEFORE setContentView
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    customSpinnerAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, colors2);
    Colors_Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Colors_Spinner);

    Initialize_UI();
}

private void Initialize_UI() {

    Colors_Spinner.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapter);
    Colors_Spinner.setSelection(0);
    Colors_Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           Colors_Spinner.setSelection( colors.indexOf(colors.get(position)));

            if ( Colors_currentSelectedItemPosition != position) {
                Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, position);
            }

            Colors_currentSelectedItemPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils
    {
         private static int sTheme;
        public final static int THEME_Blue = 0;
        public final static int THEME_RED = 1;
        public final static int THEME_PINK =2;
        public final static int THEME_GREEN =3;
        public final static int THEME_TEAL =4;
        public final static int THEME_PURPLE =5;
        public final static int THEME_LIGHTBLUE =6;
        public final static int THEME_YELLOW =7;
        public final static int THEME_ORANGE = 8;
        public final static int THEME_BROWN =9;
        public final static int THEME_GREY =10;


        public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {

            sTheme = theme;
            activity.finish();
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
            activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
        public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {

            switch (sTheme) {
                default:
                case THEME_Blue:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_RED:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.RedTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_PINK:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.PinkTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_PURPLE:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.PurpleTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_TEAL:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.TealTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_LIGHTBLUE:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.LightBlueTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_GREEN:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_YELLOW:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.YellowTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_ORANGE:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.OrangeTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_BROWN:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.BrownTheme);
                    break;
                case THEME_GREY:
                    activity.setTheme(R.style.GreyTheme);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

**CustomSpinnerAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>
{
     private Context mContext;
    private Integer  [] mColors;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, Integer [] Colors) {
        super(context, resource,Colors);
        mContext=context;
        mColors=Colors;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        TextView circle;
         if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_spinner_row, parent, false);
            circle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circle);
            convertView.setTag(circle);
          } else
            circle = (TextView) convertView.getTag();

        // Do everything you want with  "circle"
        GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)circle.getBackground();
        bgShape.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(mColors[position]));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you restart your application, the default theme used comes out from Manifest.xml in "android:theme" line inside the  tag.
If you want the persistence of choosed theme, you must save it in SharedPreferences (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).